# Standard Deviation Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a loop that takes the standard deviation of positions 1 through 3 in "y" then takes standard deviation of positions 4 through 6 etc.

Here is my code I came up with so far but am stuck since the new vector "i" increasing by those same values.

Here is a hypothetical dataset.

```
x <-rep(1:10, each =3)

y <- rnorm(30, mean=4,sd=1)

data <- cbind(x,y)

sd.v = NULL
for (i in c(1,4,7,10)){
  sd.v[i] <- sd(y[c(i,i+1,i+2)])
}
```

I am really more so interested in creating a loop rather than using `apply`, `sapply`, `tapply` or something else.

Comment: what's wrong with `sapply(seq(1,10,3), function(u) sd(y[u:(u+2)]))` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a loop, here is an approach:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(30, mean=4,sd=1)

sd.y <- as.numeric()
for(i in 1:10){
  sd.y[i] <- sd(y[(1+(i-1)*3):(3+(i-1)*3)])
}
sd.y
# [1] 0.9681038 0.3783425 1.1031686 1.1799477 0.6867556 1.6987277 
# [7] 1.8859794 1.4993717 1.2956209 1.1116502
```

Comment: Much easier than I was making it in my head.